# Need to change $EUID value to non-zero in the bash shell

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a script(test1.sh) like the below and i need to run it as root because As a prerequisites, we  need to install a couple of packages
when it  enters into this script, value $EUID should be non-zero, Coul you help me to
change this $EUID value

test1.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


....
.....

    if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
       echo "This script must be run as nonroot user. Otherwise, couple of test cases will fail."
       exit 1
    fi

.........
..........
.............
.....

..
.
.
.
.............
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Read `man sudo` https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/sudo.8.html and use `-u user`, e.g.

```
sudo -u nobody /path/to/the/script
```

Comment: I added the below lines before checking the $EUID. But is after the below executions,it still retunrs 0.    ``` useradd -m -s /bin/bash -u 15585 t4
            usermod -aG root t4
            cd XYZ1/
            su t4 -c /bin/bash
            echo $(id -u)
    ````

Comment: @SenthilAndavan please edit your attempt into your question - the formatting gets lost in comments